# How to use if statement on 2d Array on C language

Tags: arrays, c

[It says comparison between pointer and integer when i try to run this code. The purpose of the code is to check the if statement from user is same as inside the array store. eg:I stored value A20ET006 inside the ID array. then if user input the same ID,it will print something.Please help me,im new to this and sorry for my bad english.The Specific is the variable to check if the value inside is same as user input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXChz.png)

```
              char name[n][100];//n from user input
                char ID[n][100];
    for(i=0 ; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("Enter name for student %d :",(i+1));``
    scanf(" %s",&name[i]);
    printf("Enter the Id for student %d : ",(i+1));
    scanf(" %s",&ID[i]);
}
                
                for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                {
            
                    
                    if (Specific==ID[i])
                    {
                            printf("EXAM RESULT\n");
                            printf("Name    :%s\n",name[i]);
                            printf("Student ID  :%s\n",ID[i]);
                            printf("Number of question missed: %d",totalwrong[i]);
                            printf("List of question missed:\n");
                            printf("Question\tCorrect Answer\tStudent Answer\n");
                            printf("\t%c\t%c\n",scheme[i],StudentAnswer[i]);
                            printf("Percentage : %d%    ",percent[i]);
                            printf("GRED : %c ",GRADE[i]);
                    }
                    
                }
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.  Just post code in the question body. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1563833)  But I notice that that the picture and the posted code don't match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Using line `if (Specific==ID[i])` you compare the pointers (memory addresses) of the strings, not their content. To compare their content you can use e.g. [`strcmp`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function defined in `string.h`. It returns `0` if the 2 strings are equal:

```
if (!strcmp(Specific,ID[i])){....
```

Instead of `scanf(" %s",&name[i]);` please use `scanf(" %s",name[i]);`
and `scanf(" %s",&ID[i]);` ---> `scanf(" %s",ID[i]);`